# Find the area of $g_0^1(K)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a question from an exam which I don't have a solution to

> Given the following system $\begin{pmatrix}\dot{x}\\\dot{y}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&-3\\1&-2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ Setting $g_0^1:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ linear transformation that operate in the following : the point $P=(x_0,y_0)$ moves to $Q=(x_1,y_1)$ if Q is the value of solution at the point $t=1$ with IVP P at $t=0$, Looking at $K=\{(x,y):\|x\|\leq1,\|y\|\leq1\}$
> (i) what is $g_0^1(K)$
> (ii) what is the area of the set?

I don't know how to approach this and I would like to get some hints and a way of thinking about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of the matrix are $\pm 1$, then
$x=pe^t+qe^{-t}$, One ODe is $\dot x=2x-3y$ from here we get $y=\frac{p}{3}e^t+qe^{-t}$ Given that $x(0)=x_0, y(0)=y_0$. You may find $p$ and $q$ in terms of $x_0,y_0$.